# Why Java cannot find my constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, compilation

Well, maybe it is a stupid question, but I cannot resolve this problem.

In my `ServiceBrowser` class I have this line:

```
ServiceResolver serviceResolver = new ServiceResolver(ifIndex, serviceName, regType, domain);
```

And compiler complains about it. It says:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol : constructor ServiceResolver(int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

This is strange, because I do have a constructor in the ServiceResolver:

```
public void ServiceResolver(int ifIndex, String serviceName, String regType, String domain) {
        this.ifIndex = ifIndex;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.regType = regType;
        this.domain = domain;
    }
```

**ADDED:**
I removed `void` from the constructor and it works! Why?

Comment: `void ` is to be used for methods, not for constructors.

Comment: @Roman did you just answer your own question with a different account?

Comment: @Bozho, No. Another Roman is another person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

delete void from signature

```
public ServiceResolver(int ifIndex, String serviceName, String regType, String domain) {
        this.ifIndex = ifIndex;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.regType = regType;
        this.domain = domain;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have defined a method, not a constructor.

Remove the `void`

Comment: Bonho, another Roman is another person. I do not answer my question from another account.

Answer (score 2):

That's no constructor... it's a simple method that returns nothing. Absolutely nothing!

Should be this:

```
public ServiceResolver(int ifIndex, String serviceName, String regType, String domain) {
        this.ifIndex = ifIndex;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.regType = regType;
        this.domain = domain;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java constructors don't have return types on their signature - they implicitly return an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the mistake everyone makes once.  As Roman points out you have to delete "void" from infront of the the constructor.

Constructors declare no return type - which may seem odd since you do things like x = new X();  but you can consider it like this:

```
// what you write...
public class X
{
    public X(int a)
    {
    }
}

x = new X(7);

// what the compiler does - well sort of... good enough for our purposes.
public class X
{
    // special name that the compiler creates for the constructor
    public void <init>(int a)
    {
    }
}

// this next line just allocates the memory
x = new X(); 

// this line is the constructor
x.<init>(7);
```

A good set of tools to run to find this sort of mistake (and many others) are:

- [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)
- [pmd](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)
- [findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

That way when you make other common mistakes (you will, we all do :-), you won't spin your wheels so much looking for the solution.